# How to remove last 2 folder names from a file name with full path?

Tags: batch-file

How can I remove the last 2 folder in path of a file using batch script?

The result should be the last 4 folders path.

```
C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06\Test.txt
```

Should be like this:

```
C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
rem Is the batch file not called with an argument which
rem is expected to be the name of a file with full path?
if "%~1" == "" goto DemoCode

rem This code demonstrates how to get path to last but one folder
rem with accessing the file system and therefore working only if
rem the specified file respectively its folders really exist.

for %%I in ("%~dp1..\..\") do set "FilePath=%%~dpI"

rem Remove the backslash at end.
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~0,-1%"
goto DisplayResult


rem The demo code below demonstrates how to remove file name
rem and last two folders in path from a file name string with
rem complete path without accessing the file system at all.

:DemoCode
rem Get path of file ending with a backslash.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06\Test.txt") do set "FilePath=%%~dpI"

rem Remove the backslash at end.
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~0,-1%"

rem Get path to last folder of original file name with full path.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%FilePath%") do set "FilePath=%%~dpI"

rem Remove the backslash at end.
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~0,-1%"

rem Get path to last but one folder of original file name with full path.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%FilePath%") do set "FilePath=%%~dpI"

rem Remove the backslash at end a last time.
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~0,-1%"

:DisplayResult
echo/
echo File path is: %FilePath%
echo/
set "FilePath="
pause
```

There are two examples as the comments explain.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` (first argument string with surrounding double quotes removed) and `%~dp1` (drive and path of first argument).
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`